# Hobbled rook tour – Hamiltonian cycle on square grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

Consider a square grid of even side length ($2n \times 2n$). It is easy to see that there must exist a Hamiltonian cycle on the corresponding grid graph. Such a cycle is called balanced if the number of vertical edges equals the number of horizontal edges. It is easy to construct balanced Hamiltonian cycles for odd $n$. But for even $n$ I could not construct such balanced cycles nor can I prove that those cycles don't exist. Question: Does there exist a balanced Hamiltonian cycle on the grid for even $n$?

Curiously I could not find a lot of research material on this, despite it being quite a natural object. it is sometimes called a meander, for example, at [Meanders filling out an $n$-by-$k$ grid, not reduced for symmetry](http://oeis.org/wiki/Meanders_filling_out_an_n-by-k_grid_%28not_reduced_for_symmetry%29).

There is also an article that characterize and enumerate (by an algorithm) these cycles:
[Stoyan and Strehl - Enumeration of Hamiltonian Circuits in Rectangular Grids](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Eslc/s/s34erlangen.pdf).

The cycle divides the squares grid into regions (and closes one of them), and all the regions are tree (no cycle of squares that share edge). I feel that the answer to the original question will come from a clever insight into those trees.

Edit: I've made changes to make it more appropriate for MO.

Comment: the reason for the question being...?

Comment: It is a well-known olympiad problem.

Comment: A "hobbled Rook" is otherwise known as a Wazir, "a very old piece, appearing in some very early chess variants, such as Tamerlane chess."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wazir_(chess)

Comment: Do you mean, "visit each square *exactly once* in an 8 by 8 chessboard?" If not, it seems very easy to do.

Comment: @Noah. yes, it's essentially a Hamiltonian cycle on the square grid


Comment: it would be sufficient to show that for any two paths that have the same ends and contain the same grid points, their numbers of (say) vertical edges differ by a multiple of 4. From that it would follow that for n even, the difference between the numbers of vertical and horizontal ones will be 4 (mod 8) so can't be 0

Comment: I have three comments: 1, Meanders are different, there a vertex can be touched twice. 2, There is a related game called Slitherlink. 3, Similar (stronger/weaker?) concept is called Balanced Gray code.

Comment: There is a solution here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16044/10615

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: To be specific, it's from 20th TurGor of Spring 1999 - Problem 6: https://www.turgor.ru/en/problems/20/index.php#turnir20vos And here is [solution in Russian](http://pech-nik.narod.ru/Math/chess2.html) (see problem 15).

Comment: Just to be sure, the sidelength $2n$ is always even, and you are distinguishing between the case where it is singly even ($n$ odd) and the case where it is divisible by 4 ($n$ even), right?

Comment: It is truly remarkable that this question, even though about a high-school level olympiad problem not about research level maths, was never closed.

Answer (score 0):

Only a longer comment, not a complete answer.

I think of a $2n \times 2n$ chess board, where paths connect midpoints of squares.
Let the total area of the board be $2n \times 2n$.
Then the closed region (the tree), encloses an area of independent of the cycle, namely $2n^2-1$.

I have not proved this, but it seems straightforward to prove that trees with certain properties, and Hamiltonian cycles are in bijection.

When $n$ is odd, we can make a rotationally-symmetric tree, (where each of the four arm is a spiral, for example) and thus constructing a balanced path, since there is center vertex for the tree, so the $2n^2-2$ (which is divisible by $4$), can be distributed evenly in the four quadrants.

If $n$ is even, we still can put one vertex of the tree in the middle, but the $2n^2-2$ is now not divisible by $4$, and I believe this can be exploited to somehow show that said circuit is impossible.

Comment: What tree or trees are you referring to here?

Comment: @JosephMalkevitch Ok, so this was MANY years ago, but ok. A Hamiltonian path can be seen as connecting midpoints of squares. The path thus crosses some edges between squares. Now, there are some non-crossed edges, which are on the inside of the Hamiltonian path. These edges form a tree (in the graph-theoretical sense)